# Samba4 using username without the @domain name suffix

Tags: samba

I want users to login to my mail server using:

u: user1 (NOT user1@example.com)
p: password

I am using Samba4 on Zentyal for authentication.

How can I configure such that users do not have to add the domain name as username when logging in?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

You must edit this property in dovecot-ldap.conf

```
user_filter = (&(sAMAccountName=%n)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl=514)))
```

for me above, this means FIND A USER, WHERE %n is the same as sAMAccountName. (%n in ldap configurations means username before @ sign in email, %u means full email address, %d means domain).

This is searched in the LDAP database, which looks something like this, and so you can replace the `sAMAccountName=%n` part with some other UNIQUE attribute, like `mail=%u`, which mean the mail attribute in the LDAP database must match the FULL ENTRY entered by the user on login.

More can be understood by intensely looking at this: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP/Userdb

## record 54

dn: CN=Gift Rise,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=co,DC=za

cn: Gift Rise

sn: grise

...

sAMAccountName: grise

sAMAccountType: 805306368